# npm start is throwing the following error on windows

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, npm, mean

Hello I use Windows 10 and recently installed mean. However when i start npm using npm start command, i get the following error. I even installed express.

```
C:\>npm start
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path C:\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says, it's not a problem with npm itself.

It appears that npm is not able to access your package.json, or it's not present at all at the given path.
Check for the path of pacakge.json.

Also, you should do `npm init` before to create a valid package.json file, if it's not present.